# Why do the performance of DL models increase with the volume of data while that of ML models will flat out or even decrease?

Tags: theory

I have read some articles and realized that many of them cited, for example, DLis better for large amount of data than ML.

Typically:

> The performance of machine learning algorithms decreases as the number of data increases

[Source](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/deep-learning-tutorial/introduction-to-deep-learning?source=sl_frs_nav_playlist_video_clicked)

Another one says the performance of ML models will plateau,

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8zZl.png)

As far as I understand, the more data, the better. It helps us implement complex models without overfitting as well as the algorithms learn the data better, thus inferring decent patterns for accurate outputs. This should apply to both DL and ML.

So, I feel quite confused the statements from the cited sources, hopefulle guys could help me elaborate more on this matter,

Answer (score 1):

The [first source](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/deep-learning-tutorial/introduction-to-deep-learning) doesn't give a source for their claim (that performance *decreases* as you get more data), so I'd ignore it. As a rule of thumb, the more training data the harder it will be to overfit, and I think this applies to all ML algorithms. I.e. diminishing returns, but it shouldn't get worse.

The [second source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8zZl.png), the image, is what we do tend to observe, at least in the fields of image and text processing. I think one explanation is that deep learning algorithms have been better able to take advantage of modern GPUs, and thus it has been possible to scale their capacity to the point where they are able to learn from huge data sets.

Answer (score 1):

1. The claim "Performance of machine learning algorithms decreases as the number of data increases" is definitely wrong, at least in general.
2. Performance of DL model also plateau after its model capacity is reached, just like any ML model. If you think about it, any DL model is characterized by a finite set (no matter how many) of parameters, so there must be a limit on its expressiveness and thus performance. Modern DL models usually have way more parameters than *classical* ML models, which is the root cause of its superior performance but not without limit. FYI, Andrew Ng draws the complete chart in his [DL course on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning#courses)

Besides, remember DL is a **subset** of ML (not alternative), so make sure you know what it means to "compare" them.

Recommendation: stop taking anything from these sources; they are harmful to your health.

Answer (score 1):

The argument I can see in favor of the claim that most machine learning methods do worse as you add more data is that you start getting data from different sources. For instance, a mentor of mine once told me about a great speech recognition system he built, only to discover that it had badly overfit to that particular brand of microphone. That is, by getting more data, additional aspects of the patterns had to be uncovered, and his method was not up to the task.

That said, the original claim really sounds like someone being provocative, even if there is a sense in which the claim can be true.